# Cant get CNN to do multiclass classification. Throws "logits and labels must have the same shape"

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, multiclass-classification

I've tested a CNN that works fine on binary classification, but when I change the output layer from 1 to 5 and give it data with 5 labels it throws the error: ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((None, 5) vs (None, 1))

Each sample is a 190x8 matrix with a label between 0 and 4

My code looks like this:

```
testingData = loadmat('C:/Users/timwa/Desktop/Sundhedsteknologi/10.Semester/SegmentedData/Rune/Samlet/RuneStaticData19.mat')  # For small datasets
arr1 = np.array(testingData['finalData'])
tempX1=np.array([x for x in arr1[:,0]]) # Dette giver data
tempX1=np.array([x for x in tempX1])

y1=arr1[:,1] # Dette giver labels
y1.reshape(len(y1),1)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(tempX1, y1, test_size=0.25, random_state=1)
X_train = np.asarray(X_train).astype('float32')
X_test = np.asarray(X_test).astype('float32')
y_train = np.asarray(y_train).astype('float32')
y_test = np.asarray(y_test).astype('float32')

hpKernelSize = 3
hpBatchsize = 64
hpEpochs = 50 
hpPatience = 5 
hpInitialLearningRate = 0.001
hpmaxconvfilters = 32
hpPoolSize = 2
hpLRDecreaseOnPlateau = 0.1

earlyStopping = tensorflow.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=hpPatience)
reduceLROnPlateau = tensorflow.keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss',
factor=hpLRDecreaseOnPlateau, patience=math.ceil(hpPatience/2), verbose=1)
callbacks_list = [earlyStopping, reduceLROnPlateau]

inputShape = X_train.shape[1:3]
inputs = keras.Input(shape=inputShape)

x = layers.Conv1D(filters=hpmaxconvfilters, kernel_size=hpKernelSize, bias_initializer='zeros',
kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu', name='Conv1')(inputs)
x = layers.Conv1D(filters=hpmaxconvfilters, kernel_size=hpKernelSize, bias_initializer='zeros',
kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu', name='Conv2')(x)
x = layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=hpPoolSize, name='MaxPool1')(x)
x = layers.Conv1D(filters=hpmaxconvfilters, kernel_size=hpKernelSize, bias_initializer='zeros',
kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu', name='Conv3')(x)
x = layers.Conv1D(filters=hpmaxconvfilters, kernel_size=hpKernelSize, bias_initializer='zeros',
kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu', name='Conv4')(x)
x = layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=hpPoolSize, name='MaxPool2')(x)
x = layers.Flatten()(x)
x = layers.Dense(44, bias_initializer='zeros', kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu',
name='Dense1')(x)
outputs = layers.Dense(5, bias_initializer='zeros', kernel_initializer='normal',
activation='softmax', name='OutputLayer')(x)

model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs, name="CNN")
model.summary()

model.compile(loss=tensorflow.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,optimizer=tensorflow.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=hpInitialLearningRate), metrics=['accuracy',tensorflow.keras.metrics.TruePositives(),tensorflow.keras.metrics.TreNegatives(), tensorflow.keras.metrics.FalsePositives(),tensorflow.keras.metrics.FalseNegatives()])
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=hpEpochs, verbose=1,batch_size=hpBatchsize, callbacks=callbacks_list, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
```

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: The code works with 1 neuron in the output layer, but the loss is 0 and accuracy very low

Answer (score 1):

you specify the loss in model.compile as categorical_crossentropy. That implies your labels y_train and y_test must be one hot encoded. I do not see in your code that you do this. So you can either one hot encode the labels or you can change the loss function to sparse_categorical_crossentropy if your labels are integers. Below is an example of using tf.one_hot to convert integer labels to one hot encoded labels

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 0, 3])
depth = 4
b = tf.one_hot(a, depth)
# <tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 3), dtype=float32, numpy=
# array([[0., 1., 0.],
#        [1., 0., 0.],
#        [0., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32)>
```